# Astroturfer can get their profile link to stay on the main page - let's stop that

Tags: feature-request, last-activity

Low volume sites have relatively static main pages. Consider this scenario:

- A user with a name that describes their services  (Everest Tour Guides for example) answers a question with a subject line like How Do I Find a Tour Guide to Everest Base Camp?
- the answer has a link in it and not enough disclaimers, and isn't very useful. It's flagged, or a moderator comes across it
- the answer is deleted, but the account is not

Result: the last activity on the main page still shows the user's name, and is a working link to their profile. Go to [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) today to see it in action.

[image: snippet from Travel main page]

I don't think I like this. Could the "last activity" somehow show the last activity that stuck? Or list the moderator who deleted the answer as the author of the last activity?

Comment: Note that the answer-ban might handle such cases.

Comment: in that eventually they can't answer any more. But their old "last activity" droppings stick even after answers are deleted. On low volume sites the answer ban will take a while.

Comment: You could look to edit the question at that point - change the tags, correct the grammar etc - which would then update the last action to be yours instead. Only do that if there a valid edit to make though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct thing here is to just delete this user, who was obviously only created for spamming. I just did this, and now the Community user shows up as the user who "last modified".

Comment: Is [automatically destroying 1-rep spammers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165311/auto-delete-destroy-1-rep-user-when-their-post-is-deleted-as-spam) something that SE would consider? We mods can obviously just nuke the account (and I usually do that), but that doesn't work in cases where the community is able to cast enough spam flags.

Comment: My first reaction was "but what if the user isn't sufficiently awful that the account should be deleted?" but then I realized in that case I wouldn't be bothered that that link was on the main page.