# Something is wrong with posts being bumped, I think

Tags: bug, bump, homepage

There are two posts on the front page of Anime.SE that don't seem like they should be there.

[image]

[The second post in this image](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15555/1908) is four months old. It could've been bumped by Community - but if it was, the "modified yesterday Community♦ 1" thing is missing. (We have some posts further down on the front page that were Community-bumped, but no posts above that were Community-bumped. Was Community's behavior changed in the last day or so?)

[The third post in this image](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/61/1908) is more than two years old. I don't think it could have been bumped by Community, since it has an upvoted and accepted answer. Which raises the question, then, of what it's doing on the front page, despite not having been modified in two years. Also, the `.started` div doesn't have the word "modified" in it, and probably should.

Neither post has any activity recently (including deleted answers).

This is all a bit weird. A bug, mayhaps?

Comment: if you go to the posts, do they have a deleted spammy answer? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166679/astroturfer-can-get-their-profile-link-to-stay-on-the-main-page-lets-stop-tha

Comment: @KateGregory No, they don't. If I'm not mistaken, posts whose most recent activity is a deleted answer present as "modified 5 hours ago by user12345" or similar.

Comment: We had [the same issue on Worldbuilding](https://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1730/why-are-questions-with-no-recent-activity-and-not-bumped-by-community-on-the-f), but we have yet to solve it.

Comment: This is more likely a bug in the homepage caching, not bumping

Comment: What if someone suggested an edit, which made the question show, but then the edit rejected by users so no history showing, could this be the reason?

Comment: @MeNoTalk Interesting idea, but none of the [rejected suggested edits from the past week](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=week&tab=Rejected) (2k+ rep required) were on either of the two anomalous questions above.

Comment: @senshin you are right, I just suggested an edit from an anonymous user, it didn't show up...