# Add "Last Seen from IP:" To deleted/destroyed user moderator's view

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, deleted-accounts

When viewing a deleted user as a moderator, we get the following information:

```
User was deleted on 4/26/2014 3:22:58 PM
User: user1234 (1234) (Account.Id=123456789) deleted by Madara Uchiha (27)
Reason: Reason for deletion
Mod flags: 42
```

Some deleted or destroyed users are bound to open new accounts to continue trolling/spamming etc. It would be nice if we could see a deleted user's last known IP address without having to remember to remembering it before we delete it.

I propose an additional line:

```
Last seen from IP: 123.123.123.123
```

Perhaps with a link to the mod's "Accounts with this IP" page.

Comment: Taking a look at this now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for suggesting this change! I have updated the page to display the user's last known IP address along with the usual information. It will be live in the next build (> `rev 2014.6.27.2348`). Cheers!